# FPDF isnt adding new page

Tags: php, fpdf

this is the snippet of my code in which i am trying to generate pdf when their is 1 value in the array e.g

```
"$arrIds = array('10'); ".
```

My code generates the pdf, but when there are more values in the array i am unable to see the next pages.

```
  function action_pdf_reportPt10()
{
    $arrIds = array('10', '5', '12', '31');
    foreach ($arrIds as $id)
    {
        $this->_Pt10_Calculations->setPropertyId($id);
        $this->_FpdfGenerator = new Fpdf('L');
        $pt10values = $this->_Pt10_Calculations->fetch_record_by_property_id();


        $this->generate_pt10($pt10values);

    }

    $this->load->view('admin/property/report_pt10', $this->view_data);
}
```

And

```
 public function generate_pt10($pt10values)
{
    $tax_amount = round(@$pt10values[0]['tax_amount']);

    $self_rented = @$pt10values[0]['self_rent'];
    switch ($self_rented)
    {
        case '1':
            $self_rented = 'Self';
            break;
        case '2':
            $self_rented = 'Rented';
            break;
        case '3':
            $self_rented = '1)Self 2)Rented';
            break;
    }

    $location = @$pt10values[0]['location'];
    switch ($location)
    {
        case '1':
            $location = 'Main Road';
            break;
        case '2':
            $location = 'Off Road';
            break;
    }


    $baseXcoordinate = 5;

    $this->_FpdfGenerator->AddPage();
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->AliasNbPages();
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY($baseXcoordinate, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 5);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(13, 7, 'Rating Area', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY(18, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(15, 7, 'Zone', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY(33, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 5);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(25, 7, 'Area', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY($baseXcoordinate, 24);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(28, 9, 'Property No', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY($baseXcoordinate, 33);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 7);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(28, 9, 'Pin', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY(58, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(20, 7, 'Issue Date', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY(78, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 6);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->MultiCell(25, 7, 'Due Date For Payment', 1);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetXY(89.5, 10);
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->ln();
    $this->_FpdfGenerator->Output();
   }
```

i Dont know what am i missing coz for single value in array it is working fine. But when there are more then values in array it is not adding the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->_FpdfGenerator->Output();` terminates the document [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) is doc, so you should'n call it if there is some data to add

Comment: function action_pdf_reportPt10()
    {
        $arrIds = array('10', '5', '12', '31');
        foreach ($arrIds as $id)
        {
            $this->_Pt10_Calculations->setPropertyId($id);
            $this->_FpdfGenerator = new Fpdf('L');
            $pt10values = $this->_Pt10_Calculations->fetch_record_by_property_id();

                $this->generate_pt10($pt10values);
        }
        $this->_FpdfGenerator->Output();
        $this->load->view('admin/property/report_pt10', $this->view_data);
    }

Comment: thx man i actually made minor changes and it save me a big deal i took constructor of the loop and tried what u said and it works thx man. God bless u.

Comment: u're welcome. i've missed that the constructor is inside the loop too: that's not really correct.